# How to convert Employee object to student object in a list using java?

Tags: java, list, collections

I have List of employee object nearly 20 objects in a list

```
List<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
```

and I have nearly 14 student objects or it may contain empty in the list

```
List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
```

Is it possible to convert employee to student objects in the list i.e., I want employee to be converted to student object in the list.

Comment: How does an `Employee` translate to a `Student`?

Comment: Please explain your conversion strategy.

Comment: If your `Employee class` extends `Student class` then it possible

Answer (score 3):

For that you need to have some kind of relation between two different classes **Employee** and **Student**. It can be done if you have used inheritance. Or you need to use copy constructor.
Else you cannot just simply assign it.

**Edited**

If there is no relation, try using copy constructor.
**For example:**

```
Student aStudent = new Student(anEmployee);
```

And in **Student** class, define constructor as:

```
Student(Employee anEmployee){
this.name = anEmployee.getName();
// and other variables should be initialized
}
```

And of course you will need getter method in **Employee** class.
In **for** loop you need to do this which will create each student with corresponding student object that you will need to add in the list.

```
for(Student aStudent:students){
//and do it here..
}
```

Comment: but the thing is it should not have any relation.

Comment: let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

Well for long term solution for your case, just use single class which have some set of methods and class and that will be common for both and **Student** and **Employee**. And then you can share all the relevant data of that class with each other.

Comment: But for some reason, he says he doesn't want to make any relation between the classes..

Comment: @Nabin yes as i said that class is only sharing data with specific method and variables or for very basic static fields.

Answer (score 0):

> I want employee to be converted to student object in the list

Since both are incompatible interfaces/classes hence you need a way to convert it with ***minimal changes*** in the code.

[Adapter Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) might help you in this case specially read *Object Adapter pattern* section.

Read more [Adapter Pattern - GOF](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/Adapter.aspx)

> The adapter pattern is a design pattern that is used to allow two incompatible types to communicate. Where one class relies upon a specific interface that is not implemented by another class, the adapter acts as a translator between the two types.

[image]

sample code:

```
public List<Student> convert(List<Employee> employee) {
      List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
      for (Employee  e : employee) {
        // convert employee into student
        Student s = new Student();
        s.setName(e.getName());
        // set more properties
        students.add(s);
      }
      return students;
}
```